# Entirely remove empty array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using a `foreach` to build this :

```
array (size=3)
  'trainid' => string '76795' (length=5)
  'traintype' => string ' -X' (length=3)
  'userid' => string 'CPN' (length=3)

array (size=3)
  'trainid' => string '27725' (length=5)
  'traintype' => string ' -Z' (length=3)
  'userid' => string 'CPN' (length=3)

array (size=0)
  empty

array (size=3)
  'trainid' => string '00000' (length=5)
  'traintype' => string ' -X' (length=3)
  'userid' => string 'CPN' (length=3)

array (size=3)
  'trainid' => string '27921' (length=5)
  'traintype' => string ' -Z' (length=3)
  'userid' => string 'CPN' (length=3)
```

And as you see, there is an empty array and I would like to entirely remove this array. In fact, it crashs my sql script if there is an empty array.

Do you know how to remove it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), if no callback is provided, all entries equal to `FALSE` will be removed.

```
$array2 = array_filter($array);
```

Comment: Already tried. Using this does not remove the empty array.

Comment: Can you copy the content of `var_dump($array)`?

Comment: @SausauRJ check - https://eval.in/446056

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), It will automatically remove empty variable in array..

```
   print_r(array_filter($arrayvariable));
```

Comment: Already tried. Using this does not remove the empty array.